# Plotting boxplot in matplotlib with without data array?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to create plots in **matplotlib** without having raw data?

I have a tool which reports `Mean`, `Max`, `Min`, `standard_daviation`, `P_50`, `P_90`, and  `P_99`, but does not give all the data-points.  I am trying to create a plot boxplot like plot which will convey most of above properties.  But I haven't found any way to generate such a plot in matplotlib without having all the data points.  Is there any way that I can generate such a plot in matplotlib.

I have preference for matplotlib as most of the infrastructure is in Python and I am already using matplotlib for some other parts.

Comment: Yes, on current master. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2643  for details.  It will also be in 1.4.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Thats precisely what I need!  I tried to install matplotlib from the master, but ran into dependency issues of missing required package called `six` (even after doing `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib`). Quick googling did not help on how to resolve this problem.  So, it looks like getting newest version of matplotlib is fairly involved process!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what [distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html#distributions) you want - you can plot some of these like so:

```
import numpy as np
loc, scale = 0., 1 # like mean and s.d.
x=np.arange(-8., 8., .01)
laplace = np.exp(-abs(x-loc/scale))/(2.*scale)
gumbel = (1/scale)*np.exp(-(x - scale)/scale)* np.exp( -np.exp( -(x - scale) /scale) )
logistic = np.exp((loc-x)/scale)/(scale*(1+np.exp((loc-x)/scale))**2)
normal = 1/(scale * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))*np.exp( - (x - loc)**2 / (2 * scale**2) )
lognormal = (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - loc)**2 / (2 * scale**2))/ (x * scale * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))
rayleigh = (x/(scale*scale))*(np.exp((-x*x)/(2*scale*scale)))
standard_cauchy = 1/(np.pi*(1+(x*x)))


plt.plot(x,gumbel,label='gumbel scale=1')
plt.plot(x,laplace,label='laplace scale=1, loc = 0')
plt.plot(x,normal,label='normal scale=1, loc = 0')
plt.plot(x,logistic,label='logistic scale=1, loc = 0')
plt.plot(x,lognormal,label='lognormal scale=1, loc = 0')
plt.plot(x,rayleigh,label='rayleigh scale=1')
plt.plot(x,standard_cauchy,label='standard_cauchy')
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the `distribution` attribute of the data, but I only know the attributes like `mean`, `median`, `P99`, `P90`, `P50` etc.  And want a plot which shows these attributes.  Let me know if there is any way to specify these attributes.  Thanks for the answer though!